# Are there any good free online Portuguese courses?

Tags: português-europeu

I recently started to learn European Portuguese (ptPT) and I wonder if there are any good (free) online courses or webs/apps to learn and train. I already have training books etc, but I'd like to have some learning app like duolingo or babbel. Unfortunately, these websites/apps are only available in ptBR.

Anyone knows any good app/service here?

Comment: Does it have to be pt-PT? For me it seems that the language is PT and the accent can be either PT or BR. Do these apps you mentioned have separate languagew, say, en-US and en-UK?

Comment: @gmauch yes you can choose pt-PT or pt-BR. For example If you try to play a game in pt-PT or pt-BR you can find the diferences.

Comment: (I don't want to start a holy war in here), but why you're interested specifically in pt-PT? Have you already learnt pt-BR which is far more popular based in amount of natural speakers?

Comment: It HAS to be ptPT. GF is from Portugal, hence I'll definitely evade anything related to ptBR. I'm aware of the fact that those are quite similar, but it would be like speaking Austrian German in Germany.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found http://www.memrise.com/. There are apps for iOS and Android, a good Web-interface, its free, and the courses are really good. Helped me a lot so far!

They even have ptBR AND ptPT :)

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of websites are offering Free online courses (Coursera, Udemy, edx, Alison, Udacity, Khan academy and more)

You can find the best Portuguese online courses from Coursera and Udemy.